# Duplicate items on redux state tree

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, switch-statement, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update my Redux state with a toggle button. My `LB` reducer is comprised of 2 reducers, an array called `listItems` for displaying a unique number of values, and `filterBarState` which is used as a reference to the current filters.

While my initial state is correct, my reducer places the toggle action outside of `filterBarState` 
[image: Redux Logger]

Below is my LB object reducer

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EVENT_FILTER_PRESSED:
      return {
         // Reducer composition 
        filterBarState: eventFilter(state.filterBarState, action),
        listItems: eventItems(state.listItems, action)
      };
    case MALE_FILTER_PRESSED:
      // console.log('isMaleFilterOn:', action.isMaleFilterOn)
      return { ...state, isMaleFilterOn: action.isMaleFilterOn };
    case FEMALE_FILTER_PRESSED:
      // console.log('isFemaleFilterOn:', action.isFemaleFilterOn)
      return { ...state, isFemaleFilterOn: action.isFemaleFilterOn };
```

In my React Native Container Component, I have attempted some (suspect) ES6 destructuring in mapStateToProps which, if I don't include, the entire `filterBarState` returns `undefined`

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ LB }) => {

  const { filterBarState: { isMaleFilterOn, isFemaleFilterOn, currentSelectedEvent, currentSelectedRow }, listItems, isCurrentlySelected } = LB;

  return { isMaleFilterOn, isFemaleFilterOn, currentSelectedEvent, currentSelectedRow, listItems, isCurrentlySelected };
```

Any tips / suggestions on a fix would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `EVENT_FILTER_PRESSED` handler, it looks like you are not updating the `isMaleFilterOn` and `isFemaleFilterOn` at the correct level.  Try this:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EVENT_FILTER_PRESSED:
      return {
         // Reducer composition 
        filterBarState: eventFilter(state.filterBarState, action),
        listItems: eventItems(state.listItems, action)
      };
    case MALE_FILTER_PRESSED:
      // console.log('isMaleFilterOn:', action.isMaleFilterOn)
      return { ...state, filterBarState: { ...state.filterBarState, isMaleFilterOn: action.isMaleFilterOn } };
    case FEMALE_FILTER_PRESSED:
      // console.log('isFemaleFilterOn:', action.isFemaleFilterOn)
      return { ...state, filterBarState: { ...state.filterBarState, isFemaleFilterOn: action.isFemaleFilterOn } };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael and loganfsmyth!!